# How to use CanCan with Grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, grape-api

I wanna use CanCan for authorization in my API. How can I use, for example, the `authorize!` method from Grape::API module? For now, when I'm trying to use it, it returns me this: 
`undefined method 'authorize!' for #<Grape::Endpoint:0xca39664>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, `authorize!` is a addition for `ActionController::Base`, see [this source](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/2d507349700170bbefbb01a29ca6c5f83e795c83/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L393)

you can define own Grape helper:

```
class API < Grape::API
  helpers do
   def authorize!(*args)
     # you already implement current_user helper :)
     ::Ability.new(current_user).authorize!(*args)
   end
  end
end
```

or use module helper: `helpers CanCan::ControllerAdditions` (btw, I don't think is a good idea)